# Second Largest Row of Multiple Pandas Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe and would like to take the minimum of multiple 6 columns by row for example in the below table I would like to put in the below 6 rows and get the row min:

```
+-col1-col2-col3-col4-col5-col6-Min-+
| 1    2    3    4    5    6     2  |
| 6    5    4    3    2    2     3  |
| 7    8    9    10   11   12    8  |
| 90   80   70   60   70   80    70 |
```

The code I have currently put together is below:

```
a1_raw_data['Best6Sec'] = a1_raw_data.iloc[:, [21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31]].apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(2).values[-1], axis=1)
```

It is trying to take the minimum by row of columns 21, 23, 25, 27, 29 and 31. It does this by taking the nlargest rows and taking the last value in each. But I get an error message saying:

```
IndexError: ('index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are at least 2 unique values per rows first remove mising values by `dropna`, get unique values, sorting and select second value by indexing:

```
df = a1_raw_data.iloc[:, [21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31]]

a1_raw_data['Min'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.sort(np.unique(row.dropna()))[1], axis=1)

print (a1_raw_data)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6   Min
0     1     2     3     4   NaN     6   2.0
1     2     2     2     3   2.0     2   3.0
2     7     8     9    10  11.0    12   8.0
3    90    80    70    60  70.0    80  70.0
```

If possible all values per row are unique get error like:

> IndexError: ('index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1', 'occurred at index 1')

Solution is filter all non unique rows and apply solution:

```
mask = df.nunique(axis=1) != 1
f = lambda row: np.sort(np.unique(row.dropna()))[1]
a1_raw_data.loc[mask, 'Min'] = df[mask].apply(f, axis=1)
print (a1_raw_data)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6   Min
0     1     2     3     4   NaN     6   2.0
1     2     2     2     2   2.0     2   NaN
2     7     8     9    10  11.0    12   8.0
3    90    80    70    60  70.0    80  70.0
```

Comment: Sorry did the example wrong but fixed up now, I meant to put second lowest value in min column not lowest.

Comment: Thanks your method seems to be working for me. But is there a way to get it to ignore nan's as they seem to be rising to the top, I would rather it ignore them.

Comment: @ChristopherEll - It complicated solution a lot, so rather create new one.

Comment: What is df meant to be?

Comment: @ChristopherEll - It is filtered `DataFrame` - `df = a1_raw_data.iloc[:, [21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31]]`

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. I got it working using the first solution. I did have some rows that were all NaNs or had only one unique value, but didn't need them for my purposes so just removed them prior.